# Изменение цвета статика, PBM_SETBKCOLOR

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно изменить цвет статика. Вот метод которым я пытаюсь это сделать, но почему-то он не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, и как ее устранить.

```
SendMessage(Static, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, LPARAM(RGB(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue)));
```

Comment: Уточни тип элемента управления.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов TextControl

Comment: Lightness, первый раз о таком слышу. Это откуда? Можно ссылку на описание?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Описание я не знаю есть ли, но в Visual Studio 2015 он так называется. Вот скрин: 
http://i008.radikal.ru/1509/89/c235e3f16092.jpg

Comment: Всё верно, это Static Control. Смотри мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе необходимо обрабатывать сообщение WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC.

[Ответ на English SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495509/static-control-background-color-with-c).

[Пример на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Попробовал. Тоже ничего не происходит.

Comment: "Ничего не происходит" - это не ответ. Скорее всего не так пробовал.

Comment: SendMessage(Static, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, 0, LPARAM(RGB(44, 22, 77)));
Разве так не правильно?

Comment: Ты мой ответ вообще читал? Ссылки смотрел?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, но я в них пока не могу разобраться.

Comment: Чтобы обработать сообщение WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC нам нужно чтобы оно пришло. Как это сделать?

Comment: Сообщение посылается автоматически перед отрисовкой Static Control. На MSDN об этом написано.

Comment: Но а если я хочу по ходу работы программы менять цвет статика? Как в этом случае поступить?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Разберись сначала с этой проблемой.

Comment: С этой проблемой я вроде бы разобрался. Обьясните пожалуйста, как по ходу программы менять цвет и какой там принцип?

Comment: Задай новый вопрос. Тут не принято обсуждать несколько вопросов в одной теме.